# Using the same Scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

Can I use the Scanner to read from the user to enter a certain input, and then, create a new instance of it to read from a file for example?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
String fileName = sc.next();
sc = new Scanner(fileName);

displayAll(sc); //a static void method that takes the Scanner object as a parameter and is supposed to read and display the input stored in the .txt file
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Why didn't you try it?

Comment: simply use `if` ,when match found , re-initialize scanner

Comment: @PavneetSingh he has a working code. In case file name is the path to the file with the extension, it'll work

Comment: @xenteros OP said `user to enter a certain input` and then `create a new instance of it to read from a file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to use a `File`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
String fileName = sc.next();
sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
```

It would be safer to `try-catch` not-existing file. You can use `if-else`. Well... logic is up to you. Maybe something like that:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter file name");
    String filename = sc.next();
    if (!filename.startsWith("sth")) {    //this will reask if the file name doesn't start with "sth"
        continue;
    try {
        Scanner s = sc; //just in case you never gonna use System.in
        sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        s.close(); //just in case you're sure you never gonna use System.in
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong filename - try again");
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can change the `if` condition to whatever you like. I just wanted to give you a wider perspective. You can switch to `equals` if you wish ofc.

Comment: seems like you didn't read my comment either ,OP don't want this , just add an `if` condition to meet the OP requirements

Comment: @PavneetSingh yea, added. Miss entered beta version of the answer. Sorry m8

Comment: I would just add a `Scanner tmp = sc;` before the loop to close the Scanner off System.in if the file exist. If not, this instance will stays open

Comment: Closing a Scanner that's opened on System.in will also close System.in itself, and you won't be able to later re-open another Scanner on System.in.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou you're right. I applied the change to quickly

Comment: `if (!filename.startsWith("sth") {` should be `if (!filename.startsWith("sth"))`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks. Hopefuly, [so] will become so rich that they'll implement on-side IDE

Comment: That was actually a question someone asked at a talk I attended in London given by a Stack Overflow employee. He said they only offered online IDE-style inputs for Javascript and similar interpreted languages. They had no plans to do that for Java, C++ etc. due to security concerns or some similar lame excuse.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the same `Scanner` as stated in your question title. You are creating two different and independent instances of `Scanner`.

`sc` in your code is a Scanner reference. At first, it references the first `Scanner` object. Then you change the object reference to point to the second `Scanner` object. You are not reusing the `Scanner` objects, you are reusing the object reference. This is perfectly OK.

When a `Scanner` object is created, the source used by the scanner can't be changed. Get data from a different source requires a new instance to be created.

In your code example, your approach to use two different scanner for `System.in` and a file is good. However, the issue in your example is that you are using the wrong constructor for the file Scanner. To create a Scanner using the file as the source, you need to create a `File` or `Path` object and use this object as the constructor parameter instead of the filename String:

```
new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

Or:

```
new Scanner(Paths.get(filename));
```

Comment: You are correct about instanceS but is there an other solution ? Can you change the stream of the existing intance ? This should be answered in your answer ;)